# Why won't my express js app execute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, terminal

I'm having trouble executing my express js app on my localhost.  When I type:

```
christian@ubuntu:~/node_modules/nave/create$ node app.js
```

I get this as the output:

```
axconfig: port 1 not active
axconfig: port 2 not active
```

I have no idea why this is happening, last time I executed it, it worked perfectly, then my laptop crashed once, and now it won't execute.  Any help for this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well are those ports being used by another app?

Comment: I don't believe so, the only port I pointed to was port 3000 in the app.js for express.  I'm not sure what the other port is though. I ran nmap to see all ports being used and 3000 is unused.

Comment: Do you think maybe a code snippet might improve our chances of helping you resolve your problem? If I had to mind read, I say the error is on line 42, probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this post](http://dolinux.blogspot.com/2012/04/axconfig-port-1-not-active-axconfig.html), it sounds like you aren't actually running NodeJS, but [node](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/node) the radio application. You have likely used apt-get to install the wrong program.

Perhaps you ran `apt-get install node` and installed the wrong thing. If you are not using the radio application, you should `apt-get install node` to remove it since it is an entirely different program and not related to nodejs at all.

Currently when you type `node` into your prompt, it is finding `/usr/sbin/node`, which is the radio application. You should be running `/usr/bin/node` if you want to use NodeJS. In order for `node` to be resolved, you need to remove the radio app, or have `/usr/bin` in your $PATH before `/usr/sbin`

Comment: No, I've had this working completely just a day ago, then my computer shutdown adbruptly and since I haven't been able to execute this.

Comment: Do you get the node prompt if you run `node` on its own? What do you get from `which node`? Maybe your `$PATH` is wrong now for some reason.

Comment: I get axconfig: port 1 not active
      axconfig: port 2 not active from node and which node gives me /usr/sbin/node , with any path

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski Did you install node with apt, or directly? You definitely have the radio packet installed, so you should `apt-get remove node`.

Comment: I did apt-get install nodejs.

Comment: and can I still use the radio node if I get those ports active? because I'd prefer that.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski Did you happen to update Ubuntu recently?

Comment: What is your $PATH? Have you confirmed that `/usr/bin/node` exists? That's where `node` should be.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this might be a stupid question, but how do I set my $path to that?

Comment: These explain it pretty well: http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/11.html To be clear though, you want to use both the amateur radio application and NodeJS? By changing the path, you'll have to explicitly type `/usr/sbin/node` for the radio one.